# Listing all the songs that are in my favorites? ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm getting NoMethodError in Favorites#index `undefined method`name' for nil:NilClass` , and my goal is to list all the songs that are added to favorites? My code below:

**favorite_controller**

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController

  include FavoriteHelper

 def index
    @favorites = Song.all
    @songs = Song.all
    @songs = current_user.favorites
    @top_songs = Favorite.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN songs ON favorites.song_id = songs.id").select("favorites.*,songs.name as name, songs.artist_id as artist_id").group(:song_id).order('COUNT(songs.id) DESC')
  .limit(10)

  end


private

  def favorites_params
    params.require(:favorites).permit(:song_id, :user_id)
  end

end
```

**songs_controller.rb**

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_song, {only: [:edit, :update, :show, :like]}

    def index
        @songs = Song.all
        @songs = Song.search(params[:term]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).order(created_at: :desc)
        @top_songs = Favorite.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN songs ON favorites.song_id = songs.id").select("favorites.*,songs.name as name, songs.artist_id as artist_id").group(:song_id).order('COUNT(songs.id) DESC')
  .limit(10)
    @latest_albums = Album.order('created_at DESC').last(5)
    end
```

partial `_song.html.erb` to render songs in favorites

```
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
<tr>
  <th scope="row"><%= song.id %></th>
<% if logged_in? %>
  <td>
    <div class="like">
      <div class="like-btn text-center" song_id="<%= song.id %>">
        <span class="<%= song.heart_class(current_user) %>"></span>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td><%= link_to @song.name, favorite_path(song.id) %></td> 
    <td>
      <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addSong" data-id="<%= song.id %>" title="Add this song to playlist" class="open-AddSong" href="#addSong"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add to playlist"></i></a>

      <div class="modal fade" id="addSong">
        <%= render 'shared/add_song_to_playlist' %>
      </div>
    </td>

  <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
post '/song:id/like', to: 'songs#like', as: :like

  resources :songs

  resources :favorites do
    resource :songs
   end`enter code here`
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

First off (not related to the question), in your `favorites#index` action, you have:

```
@songs = Song.all
@songs = current_user.favorites
```

The first line is unnecessary and is overridden by the second line. A similar issue is in `songs#index`.

However, the problem to your question is in the partial, you need to remove the `@` in:

```
<%= link_to @song.name, favorite_path(song.id) %>
```

You don't have a `@song` variable (only `@songs` and `song`).

Comment: Thanks @Ryan! I've removed them from songs and favorites controller. But unfortunately your solution didn't work.